# JTextBox is not shown in JFrame until its clicked. Why?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am making a program and I need to make a `JTextField` in my `JPanel` that is in my `JFrame`.
Everything is set to visible. I Can see `JLabel` in the same `JPanel` but not my `JTextField`.

When I launch code below my `JTextField` is showing only when clicked. When I cross the cursor over it it changes to I know that it is there. But it is like my `JFrame` background colour.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class HomeSourceTextBox extends JTextField {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3387184252168604673L;
Dimension d = new Dimension(600, 20);

public HomeSourceTextBox() {
    setSize(d);
    setEnabled(true);
    setText("Text");

    setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sample code is not clear to provide an answer. post [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: where is the code you used to add it to the JFrame?

Comment: is there really a need to subclass `JTextField`? does it work, if you chance those propertys in a normal `JTextField`? like `JTextfield txtf = new JTextField(text); txtf.setSize(...)`

Comment: You should consider using layout managers instead of messing with hardcoded sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing but I think you are trying to make `JTextField` *longer*.

To give your `JTextField` a default amount of columns use [JTextField(int columns)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField%28int%29) constructor like so:

```
JTextField jtf=new JTextField(10);
```

And as others have suggested please do post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can see specific problems.

As a general note though its always better to override `get|Minimum|Maximum| Preferred |Size` or `set|Minimum|Maximum| Preferred |Size`,so that `LayoutManager`s cant change the size (if you are not using a `Layout` I highly suggest you do though).

I prefer the `getPreferredSize()` and the docs agree -
[`JTextField` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#getPreferredSize%28%29)

> `getPreferredSize()`
>
> *Returns the preferred size Dimensions needed for this TextField. If a non-zero number of columns has been set, the width is set to the
>   columns multiplied by the column width.*

Comment: Hell Yeah. I just needed to set how many columns I want in my TextField. As I made all the code in the constructor did not set it.

Answer (score 0):

If setting the appropriate length doesn't do the trick...

You could try (re)validating the container the textbox is placed on.
Sounds like the object tree is there, but the canvas isn't being updated. Calling repaint() or validate() (*which also calls repaint()*) on the container (in your case the JPanel) forces a re-draw.

Comment: *Calling repaint() or validate() (which also calls repaint())* as far as I know `validate()` does not call `repaint()` and vice versa. That is why we have to call them both i.e `validate(); repaint();` before changes can be reflected. and this only applies when added to an alreadyt visible container

Comment: You're absolutely right, just double checked the jdk source... My bad.